# In Rails, How do you apply different serializers for each model/object in the same render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my render, I have

```
reder json: {code_names: @code_names, rows: @tables}, each_serializer: FreeTableSerializer
```

Where `@code_names` is just an arbitrary list, which doesn't matter much in our problem, and `@tables` can be a collection of obejcts of one model.

If I use `each_serializer` in this case, I'm assuming the each goes trough json's "children", which are both lists and it ends up not applying the serializer into `@tables`.

I want a way to return both `@code_names` and `@tables` with `@tables` using a Serializer that is no its default.

I tought about making a single variable that is a single list, but I need a way to identify both code and tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define a composite serializer

```rb
class ACompositeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def serializable_hash
    tables_serializer_hash.merge code_names_serializer_hash
  end

  private

  def tables_serializer_hash
    FreeTableSerializer.new(object, options).serializable_hash
  end

  def code_names_serializer_hash
    CodeNameSerializer.new(object, options).serializable_hash
  end
end
```

**update**

in your case, i think just simple like this:

```rb
render json: {
 code_names: @code_names.as_json, 
 rows: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(
  @tables,
  serializer: FreeTableSerializer
 )
}
```

Comment: I did as you said, but got not results... Not sure if it was my mistake. It seems like neither objects had the serializer applied. I tried putting a byebug in each function, and none of them activated, except the one right under class (So I guess the serializer is being called). Also, code_names doesn't have a serializer, and I would like the code to be coherent with it. Serializer: (https://prnt.sc/13etrff), Controller: (https://prnt.sc/13etumm).

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues my bad, i guess you're using `active_model_serializers` gem, right ? the composite serializer just work for activerecord object. i updated my answer to suggest a simple way for your case.

Comment: Ahhhh it all makes sense now. I did find the first answer before, but it didn't work. Would you mind editing your answer to include the difference beteween each answer? Also, thanks for the answer!